# PowerPivot Data Refresh Schedule Timeout Error

Tags: 2016, powerpivot, data-refresh

I am getting timeout error when I schedule data refresh, but I can refresh data manually. Data refresh unattended account has enough permissions for database server and tables. Is there any idea why I am getting this error?

```
The operation has timed out
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved.

This issue is caused by a change to the design of the product in SharePoint 2016 that limits a single PowerPivot data source to a refresh duration of 100 seconds (or 1:40). Note that this can also be caused by slow or underperforming data sources if you think your data should be refreshing in under 100 seconds. If you are pulling a small amount or data from a complex data source that takes a long time to query, you may consider alternative workarounds as increasing the timeout may not be the best option.

[image]

[Here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/excel_services__powerpivot_for_sharepoint_support_blog/2017/04/14/powerpivot-for-sharepoint-2016-scheduled-data-refresh-error-the-operation-has-timed-out/) is more info.